# How to remove two commas of a csv file using c

Tags: c, csv

My csv file looks something like this:

> Alice,Girl,19,Beauty
>
> Alec,,30,cool

Now as shown in the above sample there are two commas in the second entry. Right now I am using the following instruction in c to read the csv and store it in the data structure 'data':

```
fscanf(filename,"%[^,],%[^,],%d, %[^,]", data.name,data.gender,&data.age,data.att);
```

How do I ignore the second comma? Is there any way I can write `%[^,^,]` for accommodating the 2 commas?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Use `strsep` insted of it if available.

Comment: For strsep,  How do I go about using it in my program? I am not inputting any string.

Comment: If you are reading from a text file, you can read each line with `fgets`. Then you have a string, to which you can apply `strsep`. There is also the function `strtok` but it won't handle consecutive commas, it will treat them as a single comma, that is, ignore an "empty" field.

Comment: `","` --> `"%*[,]"`

Comment: sample [code](https://ideone.com/Q6IPzb)  of using `strsep`

Comment: The `scanf()` conversion specifications do not allow for empty inputs so you can't use `sscanf()` et al to process the data easily. In a context like this, I'd be using `fgets()` or equivalent to read lines and then parsing the CSV data — preferably with a CSV library, but failing that with `strspn()` and/or `strcspn()`, or perhaps `strsep()`, as shown.  CSV libraries aren't all that hard to write, but neither are they particularly easy if you need to deal with quoted entries that contain commas or quotes, etc. as in the full CSV specification ([RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)).

Answer (score 2):

Example using `strsep` (check omitted)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Implementation as an example as it is not a standard function
//It is unnecessary when it is usable
char *strsep(char **sp, const char *sep){
    char *p, *s;
    if (sp == NULL || *sp == NULL || **sp == '\0') return NULL;
    s = *sp;
    p = s + strcspn(s, sep);
    if (*p != '\0') *p++ = '\0';
    *sp = p;
    return s;
}

typedef struct data {
    char name[32];
    char gender[8];
    int age;
    char att[96];
} Data;

int main(void){
    const char *filename = "data.csv";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    Data data;
    char buff[128];
    char *token, *p;

    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp)){
        p = buff;
        token = strsep(&p, ",\n");//1st field
        strcpy(data.name, token);
        token = strsep(&p, ",\n");//2nd field
        strcpy(data.gender, token);
        token = strsep(&p, ",\n");//3rd field
        data.age = atoi(token);
        token = strsep(&p, ",\n");//4th field
        strcpy(data.att, token);
        //check print
        printf("DEBUG:\nName:'%s', Gender:'%s', Age:%d, Attribute:'%s'\n",
            data.name, data.gender, data.age, data.att);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```